# Access shared file/folder by relative path

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am building a client to access files in the user's OneDrive, using MSGraph SDK (for .net, running on Android).

I have calculated the sharedId so I can access

```
client.Shares[shareId].Root.Children
                .Request()
                .GetAsync()
```

where shareId is a string in the form `u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL2YvcyFBdHVBTV9OYWN3VmFoaUZwdU1HU19CaVFDd1d1`(calculated as described in [the API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online#encoding-sharing-urls)

Now I would like to list the contents of a subfolder, so I call

```
client.Shares[shareId].Root.ItemWithPath("subfolder").Children
                .Request()
                .GetAsync()
```

where "subfolder" is an existing subfolder name.

However, I retrieve `Resource not found for the segment 'root'` when calling `ItemWithPath()`.

To my understanding, this accessing of files relative to another item should work according to [the docs on path-based-addressing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online#path-based-addressing) (and it works for files/folders inside the users drive, but not for items inside a share).

Is this a limitation and do I need to store the driveItemId for each shared file I want to access? Or is there an easier solution so I can handle shared files the same way as files in the user's drive?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it appears this kind of path based addressing is not supported. But the following options could be considered instead

**Option 1**

Split the single request into the following sub requests:

- get *parent* folder by  `shareId`: GET /shares/{shareId}/root
- get sub folder items by providing `DriveItem.Id` of parent folder along with `Drive.Id` from previous request:   `GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-item-id}:/{sub-folder-name}:/children`

Here is an example:

```
var parentDriveItem = await graphClient.Shares[shareId].Root
     .Request()
     .GetAsync();


var items = await graphClient.Drives[parentDriveItem.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[parentDriveItem.Id]
    .ItemWithPath(subFolderName)
     .Children
     .Request()
     .GetAsync();

     //print results
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
     }
```

**Option 2**

The idea is to address drive item by *generating sharing token for a sub folder*.
[Given the implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#encoding-sharing-urls) for encoding a sharing URL, a method (`UrlDecode`) for decoding  it back is also introduced:

```
public static class SharingUtility
{
    public static string UrlEncode(string value)
    {
        var base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
        return "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/','_').Replace('+','-');
    }

    public static string UrlDecode(string encodedValue)
    {
        var safeEncodedValue = encodedValue.Replace('_','/').Replace('-','+').Substring(2) + "==";
        var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(safeEncodedValue);
        var value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now the sharing token could be generated based on sharing token for parent folder:

```
var parentShareId = SharingUtility.UrlEncode(sharingUrl); //refers to parent folder
//generate share id for sub folder
var shareId = SharingUtility.UrlEncode(SharingUtility.UrlDecode(parentShareId) + "/" + subFolderName);  
//address shared drive item 
var items = await graphClient.Shares[shareId].Root.Children
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, option 2 seems to work only for OneDrive for Business accounts. On my personal OneDrive account, the WebUrl is not constructed from the local path.

Comment: @Philipp, indeed, option 2 in case of OneDrive Personal does not seem reliable